# How to customize properties binding from environment variables using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to get binded properties from environment variable to a map. If a property is defined in `application.properties` **binding works correctly**. But if the property is defined as an ENV variable bindings fails.

Consider following example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.test")
public class Props {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> property;
}
```

Following ENV variable is expected to be mapped as a Map `[property={foo={bar=VALUE}}]`.

```
export COM_TEST_PROPERTY_FOO_BAR=VALUE
```

But the binding failing

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'property[FOO_BAR]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'property[FOO_BAR]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

---

Based on [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion) I've also tried to create a custom `Converter` and using `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding` register it but with this approach I am not able to access keys, just values.

I've also tried to register custom `PropertyEditor`, but it looks like is not getting registered, maybe it should be registered in different way?

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public CustomEditorConfigurer customEditorConfigurer() {
    CustomEditorConfigurer pe = new CustomEditorConfigurer();
    pe.setCustomEditors(Collections.singletonMap(Map.class, KeyPropertyEditor.class));
    return pe;
}
```

You can try it out using this [Demo app](https://github.com/peterjurkovic/spring-boot-binding-demo)

---

**Edit 1**
I've raised **[an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8902)**

---

**Edit 2**

It will be fixed in Spring Boot 2

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, you want to import a whole namespace of properties in a single environment variable ? I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : regarding what you really want : use the following as your application.properties file.

```
com.test.some.key=${COM_TEST_PROPERTY_SOME_KEY}
com.test.other.key=${COM_TEST_PROPERTY_OTHER_KEY}
```

I know it's bothersome but It should do the trick.

You can also post-process every properties starting by COM_TEST_PROPERTY, parse them, split them into the path you want and inject them into your environment but that would require more code.

Comment: I've tried this. The converter does not help. Because you have an access just to a values. So in this case it would be saved as `[property={FOO_BAR=VALUE}]`

Comment: you could have an early configuration file that would load the whole map and reinject every subkey into the environment.

Comment: Binding works correctly form configuration files (`application.properties`). I need externalized configuration - EVN variables. I've also raised **[an  issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8902)** because the binding is not consistent.

Comment: Yeah, I finally understood. But then, you should have a single environment variable per property. Not a map of property path & values in a single variable. you could hack that by binding a Map to your environment variable and inject every subkey manually in your environment during start-up but it would be bad design in my opinion.

Comment: The reason why I need it like this is that `COM_TEST_PROPERTY_<DYNAMIC_VAL>_<DYNAMIC_VAL>`=VALUE thanks for help anyway

Comment: Yes, but that's not how it works. The environment variable name is a name, not a path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141716/discussion-between-peter-jurkovic-and-jeremy-grand).